# I ran this code but it didn't run on the console

Tags: java

```
#package loops;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fabbonacchi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;

        System.out.print(a + " ");
        System.out.print(b + " ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
            int c = a + b;
            System.out.print(c + " ");
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this code but its not running. I mean on the console ..

Comment: How did you run the code? What do you mean by it's not running? What error are you getting?

Comment: Your code running perfectly. I think you are not getting anything on console when you run your code so for better visualization  just put this System.out.println("Enter number"); before int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;

Comment: even if you don't put anything extra  and just type any number in console after you  run you will get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running perfectly fine.
Remember you suppose to add a integer on the console.

To get more guidance run like this, on the (for) statement line add:

```
System.out.print("Type the number\n"+c + " ");
```

then type out the integer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply need to write some integer on the console and then you will see proper output on the console. First you created a Scanner object then assigned a input from console to n variable, everything after n initialization will run after you provide some value to n. So when you run the program what you get is empty console, write 10 for example and everything will be fine.